# Error: Step implementation missing for: [step_definition] when trying to run a scenario using cucumber with cypress 10

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have updated my project to cypress 10.  But getting this error couldn't solve the problem described in the title.

my feature file:
[image]

spec file:
[image]

Error:
[image]

File order:
[image]

Config file:
[image]

package.json file:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a mistake to use both `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` and `@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` in the same project.

Uninstall `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`, it is a defunct version.

Then follow badeball [Example setup](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/HEAD/docs/quick-start.md#example-setup) to make corrections to the configuration, for example

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import createBundler from "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    async setupNodeEvents(
      on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
    ): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {
      // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        "file:preprocessor",
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
        })
      );

      // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi Thankyou for your support. Im getting errors in these lines
on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
      config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
    ): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions>